# Developing pi based python DSLR timelapse script, to now function via cell, power cycle camera, and have stepper motors

Tags: raspberry-pi-os, python-2.x

I'm working on a Pi project with to control a DSLR camera for time-lapse photography. I've successfully set up triggering and internal transfer python  scripts with Gphoto2 and am now looking to expand my project with the following tasks:

1. Remote Access & Image Transfer: I aim to enable remote camera control and image transfer via cellular connectivity, using SFTP to upload images to the cloud.
2. Camera Power Control: I need to control the DSLR camera's power supply, allowing it to power cycle between shots and turning it off at night.
3. Stepper Motor Control: I plan to use a stepper motor (or similar) to act as a rain wiper and potentially rotate the camera rig.

I'm seeking advice on specific modules or HATs that can help me achieve these goals. I'm open to recommendations, including suggestions for a different Raspberry Pi model if it would be more suitable for this project.

Here are my questions:

- Do you have any specific module or HAT recommendations that are known to work well together for a time-lapse photography project with a Raspberry Pi?
- How should I allocate GPIO pins and other resources to ensure smooth operation of these modules?
- Are there any known compatibility issues when combining these modules for my specific use case?
- What additional components or accessories might I need to support this project, given the DSLR camera control and time-lapse functionality?
- Can you recommend any software libraries or resources to help coordinate the operation of these modules for a seamless DSLR time-lapse system?

I'm 14 years old and new to this so appreciate your guidance and support. Thank you for your help